# Custom URL for Salesforce CRM

Tags: custom, url, instance

I'm facing the intriguing question of trying to customize the standard Salesforce URL, i.e. https://**[instance].salesforce.com**/

It's in particular the bit in bold that I'd like to understand if it is possible to change/customize/hack.

Has any of you faced this question/problem before?
Any solution or possible workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=domain_name_overview.htm&type=0) it says, that

> After you deploy your domain, it’s activated immediately, and requests
>   with the original URL are redirected to your new domain. Only
>   Salesforce Customer Support can change your domain name after it’s
>   deployed.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, but my question was more deep, I'd like to understand if there's any way to change the URL with something custom, not only the sub-domain (like in https://[custom_subdomain].my.salesforce.com), so, for instance: https://customdomain.com

Comment: @die-vil, no, there is no such option. Again, from documentation `Your domain name uses standard URL format, including:
Protocol: https://
Subdomain prefix: your brand or term
Domain: my.salesforce.com
Your name can include up to 40 letters, numbers, and hyphens. You can’t start the subdomain name with root, status, or a hyphen.`